# Unable to install collections from GitLab to RHEL AutomationHub

Tags: git, automation, ansible, gitlab

Unable to install collections in our NameSpace from GitLab to RHEL Automation Hub.
Actually I want to pull many Ansible Playbooks which are stored in GitLab repo. I have mentioned below the script. Please correct me if I'm wrong anywhere.

```
cat requirement.yaml

collections:
  - name: https://gitlab.com/organization/CiscoAutomation.git
    token: <tokenName>
    type: git
    version: 1.0

cat ansible.cfg

[defaults]
COLECTIONS_PATH = ./collections


$ ansible-galaxy install -r requirements.yml
Executed without any error but nothing has installed.
then I tried this below command also after SSH
ansible-galaxy collection install git@github.com:organization/ciscoautomation.git

[root@autohub01 CADir]# ansible-galaxy collection install git@gitlab.com/ciscoautomation.git -vvv 
ansible-galaxy 2.9.15
  config file = /root/CADir/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-galaxy
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Mar 18 2021, 08:58:41) [GCC 8.4.1 20200928 (Red Hat 8.4.1-1)] Using /root/test/ansible.cfg as config file Found installed collection davidban77.gns3:1.5.0 at '/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/davidban77/gns3'
Found installed collection bonddim.linux:1.2.1 at '/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/bonddim/linux'
Found installed collection community.docker:1.6.1 at '/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/docker'
Found installed collection community.general:3.1.0 at '/root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/community/general'
```

When I tried in AutomationHub GUI for import the collections in our NameSpace, It doesn't accept the yaml or txt format.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching about ansible collections and have encountered into the same problem. Your question helped me to resolve my problem. The only difference is that I am using SSH URL to pull down a collection from Gitlab. Here are my settings for collections block that I have in the requirements.yml file:

```
collections:
  - name: namespace.collection_name
    source: git@gitlab.some-company.com:username/collection_name.git
    type: git
    version: develop
```